# How to make a function periodic?

Tags: polynomials, periodic-functions, trigonometry

I have a nice little equation here, $f\left(x\right)=\frac{4}{\pi ^2}\left(x+\frac{\pi }{2}\right)^2-1$, which ever so nicely approximates (with somewhat good accuracy), a period of the sine function, and then goes to nothingness (because it's a parabola). Using the inverse of the function I can get the other period of the sine function.

How do I "combine" these two equations (the equation and it's inverse) to make one periodic function representing $\sin\left(x\right)$?

[This desmos graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/7s42bykmor) may help.

Comment: I think you have to use the heaviside function or otherwise you will have to come up with some cubic function that does not have anything to do with your $f(x)$.

Comment: The leading coefficient should be $\frac 1{(\frac \pi 2)^2}=\frac 4{\pi^2}$  As written, the $2$ is not squared and $f(0) \neq 0$

Comment: @cr001 if I have to I will. This was just a fun experiment I did to see if I actually could approximate a trigonometric function. I'm always looking for a tiny, finite trig approximation :D

Answer (score 3):

Define it to be periodic.  Let $y=x \pmod {2 \pi}$, then $$f(x)=\begin {cases} \frac 4{\pi^2}\left(y-\frac \pi 2\right)^2-1&0 \le y \le \pi\\-\frac 4{\pi^2}\left(y-\frac {3\pi} 2\right)^2-1&\pi \le y \le 2\pi\end {cases}$$
This is a fine function.  It returns a unique value for each input.

Comment: This doesn't really make an equation and it's inverse into one periodic equation... I don't want any logical comparisons in my code! `(if 0 <= y && y <= Math.PI)`

Comment: I don't understand the resistance to functions defined by cases.  You are not alone-we see this a lot.  If you find a better answer, use it.  You can hide the cases in a floor function, using $(-1)^{\lfloor \frac y \pi \rfloor}$ but it amounts to the same thing.

Comment: Nothing against it, just that I try to save every nanosecond when I'm making a low latency method